# Is Blender 2.79 Obsolete now?

Tags: modeling

I was excited about Blender 2.8 but was disappointed at the same time because I had to relearn the software. It seem everything is out of place.

Is 2.79 no longer an option? I mean, is it a bad investment to spend time in 2.79 now that 2.8beta is out? The process of relearning the UI is just frustrating for me. :(

Comment: I think the big changes with 2.8 are the UI, the  Collections, Grease Pencil and Eevee. But all the basics of modeling, rigging, animating, etc... stay the same, so the time you spend on 2.79 won't be lost. Plus I guess there are still some bugs with 2.8 (?)

Comment: If learning UI and getting it into your memory is not your strong suit maybe you should start sooner so you have enough time to adapt so you can jump right into 2.8 when it is released. Maybe 2.8 does not have any new features you want, but in future I am sure it will, so you will switch anyways. You might as well do it now when you are younger and your brain learns faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in 2.79 is essentially still available in 2.8 and more. Technically 2.8 is still in the open testing phase, but I would recommend learning it now. It doesn't take as long as one may think to figure out where everything is, and I think it's stable enough to replace 2.79. That being said, there's no shame in sticking to 2.79 for now.

Answer (score 1):

This question was marked as opinion based, however I believe it can have a definite answer that is not an opinion:

No, Blender 2.79 is not obsolete now. In fact it is the current version until 2.80 is released, that has not happened yet at the time I am writing this.

In addition to that it is a fact, that version 2.79 is planned to be made available for download in the future when 2.80 is released like every other [previous version same as these here](https://download.blender.org/release/) and it is also going to remain free for downloading so there will definitely be nothing stopping anyone from using it in the future.

Those are the facts. Now in regard to your frustration when learning new things I can only say that it is natural. Learning requires some struggling and it can be a slight shock when one is used to working smoothly. I would not worry about it and carry on learning despite the occasional frustration keeping in mind that is a natural process and only means you are learning and getting better. It is very reasonable to assume that the frustration will most likely disappear with time as your skills of using the new features improve and you will be able to enjoy it again once you get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a few things:

- if your hardware and system meet the requirements: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements
- the actual use. If you are into 2D animations, choose 2.8x for the Grease Pencil that now is a proper animation tool
- if you feel you are ready to make another step
- if Blender is your job or fun (great if it's both)

In fact only dated software, eg. Blender 2.3x/2.4x may be obsolete as it's **hardware** that it goes way faster with.
So, 2.79 is **by no means** obsolete. You there in the West have been trained to thrash things even before you get new ones. You go so fast one day you smash your head and won't even notice it.